# .NET - How to remove 3D-Shading from a checkbox in an .xlsx-file

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, apache-poi, openxml

After populating an existing xlsx-file with data using NPOI, I am saving it. This spreadsheet contains some checkboxes, and after saving the file the checkboxes have a border around them and 3D-shading enabled. I want to remove both of these properties to restore the original look of the document. I have tried using the `DocumentFormat.OpenXml`-package and the Office-Interop. I was able to remove the border using the latter, but the 3D-Shading still remains. Can anybody show me how to remove it? The code:

OpenXml:

```
            Using document As SpreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(tempFile, True)

                Dim workbookPart As WorkbookPart = document.WorkbookPart

                For Each ws As WorksheetPart In workbookPart.WorksheetParts

                    For Each control In ws.ControlPropertiesParts
                        control.FormControlProperties.NoThreeD = "1"
                        control.FormControlProperties.Save()
                    Next

                    ws.Worksheet.Save()

                Next

                document.Save()
                document.Close()

            End Using
```

Interop:

```
            Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application()
            Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(tempFile)
            Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

            For Each s As Excel.Worksheet In xlWorkbook.Sheets
                xlSheet = s

                s.Cells(12, 1).Value = "TEST"

                Dim shapes As Excel.Shapes = xlSheet.Shapes
                For Each shape As Excel.Shape In shapes
                    If shape.Name.Contains("Check Box") Then
                        shape.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse
                        shape.ThreeD.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse
                    End If

                Next

                Dim lstObjects As Excel.ListObjects = xlSheet.ListObjects
                For Each lstObj As Excel.ListObject In lstObjects
                    Debug.Print(lstObj.Name)
                Next

                Dim oleObjects As Excel.OLEObjects = xlSheet.OLEObjects()
                For Each oleObj As Excel.OLEObject In oleObjects
                    Debug.Print(oleObj.Name)
                Next
            Next

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlSheet)
            xlSheet = Nothing

            xlWorkbook.Close(True)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook)
            xlWorkbook = Nothing

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp)
            xlApp = Nothing
```

Comment: I was looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.office2010.excel.formcontrolproperties?view=openxml-2.8.1, but couldn't find a property there. That said, have you inspected the XML between the shadowed file and the non-shadowed file to see the difference?

Comment: `<formControlPr xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main" objectType="CheckBox" lockText="1" noThreeD="1"/>` is the XML for a checkbox without the 3D-stuff. The checkbox looks normal (i.e. no 3D) when the sheet is printed, so it's actually no longer a problem for me

Comment: Put your comment as an answer, and then accept it